# Mysql Query With JOIN and Nested NOT IN

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables.
One is questions table and another one is the answers table with the below mentioned schema.

Question:

`id` `title` `category_id` `active`

Answer:

`id` `question_id` `player_id` `active`

Basically, what I need is a query to get the number of questions remaining  grouped together for each player for a particular `category_id`

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(s.question_id) FROM answers s)
```

It returns me the remaining questions, but its not grouped together for particular player and if it is joined with the same answers table, then  the result set is empty.

Query that I have tried:

```
SELECT g.player_id, COUNT(questions.question_id) as Count
FROM    `questions` JOIN answers g ON g.id = questions.id
WHERE g.question_id NOT IN
    (
    SELECT  DISTINCT(question_id)
    FROM  answers
    ) GROUP BY g.player_id
```

I have already got the desired result using *PHP* and used multiple loops to get the required set and it is not optimized solution and takes a lot of time. So, want to solve it by writing a proper query.

Thanks for your time and appreciate if anyone can guide me.

Table Data:

Questions:

```
id title category_id active
 1   A     1          1
 2   B     1          1
 3   C     1          1
 4   D     1          1
 5   E     1          1
```

Answers:

```
id question_id player_id active
 1    1           1       1
 1    3           1       1
 1    2           2       1
 1    4           3       1
```

Expected Output:

```
 player_id Count_of_Remaining_Questions Category ID
   1            3                           1
   2            4                           1
   3            4                           1
```

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Comment: @Strawberry Oh! Forgot that. Thanks. Will keep in mind. Waiting for the query.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge Updated. Thanks.

Comment: What if no-one had answered anything yet, where would you get your list of players from?

Comment: @trincot Hmm, that is also another case. I guess we have to join it with the players table as well.

Comment: @KinshukLahiri That would actually be easier. ;)

Comment: @trincot However, I only need the data for the players present under the answer table.

Comment: @Paul Complete noob in SQL ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume a `players` table with this simplified schema:

```
id | name
```

Now you can join this table with your questions table:

```
SELECT 
  p.id AS player_id,
  q.id AS question_id
FROM
  players p
CROSS JOIN
  questions q
```

That would result in a list of all possible player-question combinations. Now, you could join that to the answers using a LEFT JOIN and filter out the answered ones:

```
SELECT 
  p.id AS player_id,
  q.id AS question_id
FROM
  players p
CROSS JOIN
  questions q
LEFT JOIN
  answers a 
    ON a.question_id = q.id 
    AND a.player_id = p.id
WHERE
  a.id IS NULL
```

This will reduce the former list to all unanswered questions. Now, just group that by player and category to get the final list:

```
SELECT 
  p.id AS Player,
  COUNT(q.id) AS Remaining,
  q.category_id AS Category
FROM
  players p
CROSS JOIN
  questions q
LEFT JOIN
  answers a 
    ON a.question_id = q.id 
    AND a.player_id = p.id
WHERE
  a.id IS NULL
GROUP BY
  p.id,
  q.category_id
```

Update: To get a list of players who already answered all questions we need to change the logic. Instead of checking for unanswered questions (`WHERE a.id IS NULL`) we will now compare the sum of question ids in both tables `questions` (to get the reference for all questions) and `answers` (to calculate the score for each player/category). Only if both values are equal (`HAVING SUM(a.question_id) = SUM(q.id)`), the individual player did answer all questions (assuming there is only one answer row per player and question.

```
SELECT 
  p.id AS Player,
  COUNT(q.id) AS Remaining,
  q.category_id AS Category
FROM
  players p
CROSS JOIN
  questions q
LEFT JOIN
  answers a 
    ON a.question_id = q.id 
    AND a.player_id = p.id
GROUP BY
  p.id,
  q.category_id
HAVING
  SUM(a.question_id) = SUM(q.id)
```

Comment: Thanks, for your help. It works like a Charm. I did some little changes. However, I have one more thing to ask. It doesn't returns any player_id for any particular category when they have 0 question remaining. Can we get only those players count, whose questions remaining is 0?

Comment: Well, that's another task. By adding `WHERE a.id IS NULL` we specifically only list players that have at least one question remaining. Could you specify the requirements? That is, now you want a list of players that have answered all questions?

Comment: Yes, all the players who have answered all the questions.

Comment: Thanks! Doing the task with SQL shows huge improvements at my end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cross join for get all the possible question for each user then   with a not in the asnwer  of each user you could obtain the value for your stats

```
   select player_id, count(*), category_id
   from (

      select a2.player_id, q.id, q.category_id 
      from answer  a2
      cross join question q 
      where (a2.player_id, q.question_id ) not in (
         select a.question_id, a.player_id
         from Answers a ) 
    ) t
    group by player_id, category_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You could cross join the `answers` and `questions` tables and then outer join the `answers` table again to find the missing answers:

```
select     a.player_id, 
           count(distinct q.id) as count
from       answers a
cross join questions q
left join  answers a2
        on a2.question_id = q.id
       and a2.player_id = a.player_id
where      a2.question_id is null
and        q.category_id = 1
and        q.active = 1
group by   a.player_id
```